# Looking for a free system monitoring tool

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, performance, activity-monitor

I'm looking for a system monitoring tool, preferably a free one. I don't care if it's an actual app or sits in my terminal.

Activity Monitor doesn't give me all the information I want at once.

iStat Menus definitely seems like a slick option, but that costs $. I use iTerm2/zsh/oh-my-zsh; I haven't been able to find any sort of plugin for that, which is disappointing.

Comment: What information do you want?

Comment: iStatMenus is definitely worth the $16, if only for the network throughput monitor.

Comment: Without specifics about what you require, all answers will be opinions. Please re-word the question to include specifics, or, reword the question to ask which software packages are available for system monitoring. It would also help to know your specific OS. Lastly, have you tried the `top` command?

Answer (score 5):

There are two that come to mind immediately (since you mentioned iStats Menu).

1) [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) is a free CPU, memory, disk, and network monitoring tools for Mac OS X. It can run in the menu bar just as iStats Menu does.

[image]

2) [atMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/) offers a better alternative to Apple's own "Activity Monitor" and combines the best of the features of many other existing monitoring utilities. It also adds an extensive list of unique features of its own. In addition to the standard CPU, Disk and Network info, atMonitor allows interaction with processes, setting up triggers, logging, purging RAM and much more. atMonitor can be displayed...

[image]

As a standalone floating window...

[image]

As a menu bar...

Of the two, atMonitor is the one I prefer, but, as always, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It was surprisingly hard for me to find a decent free app.

Two decent apps are listed [here](http://www.guidingtech.com/32837/best-system-monitoring-apps-mac/)

1. [MagicPaster](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/magicanpaster/id427378978?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D8) [image: MagicPaster Widgets]
2. [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/index.html) [image: MenuMeters Widgets]

Answer (score 0):

Although not free StatsBar is pretty good: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/statsbar-system-monitor/id596743393?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

If you act quickly you can get it for $2 as its 75% off right now.